# Convergence of sequence with $\zeta$ function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, riemann-zeta

Last time I heard interesting question. Unfortunately I do not have idea how to solve it, so I decided to give it here.

Let us define sequence $a_n=(\underbrace{\zeta\circ...\circ \zeta}_{n})(\pi)$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, where $\zeta$ is Riemann zeta function. 
$\textbf{Question}:$ What we can say about the convergence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ ? If this sequence has a limit what we can say about it ? Is it a rational number ?

I tried to do some numerical calculations to see how it behaves for large $n$ and it looks like this limit is equal $1$, but I don't have any idea how to prove it.

Comment: I doubt that it converges to 1. We have always $a_n>1$ and if $|a_n-1|<\epsilon$ with a small $\epsilon$ you have a large $a_{n+1} = \zeta(1+\epsilon) \approx \epsilon^{-1}$. But there is a fix point $\zeta(s)=s$ with $f\approx  1.83377265168.$

Comment: This seems to be an essay on iterating zeta: http://primepatterns.tumblr.com/post/124473646036/riemann-zeta-function-ζ-in-the-neighbourhood-of